# put date & time in each line using data in the file

Tags: linux, shell

can some one help me for the output below:

before:

```
Thu May 27|14:23:17.068|A|0002|MSU Received Last Min|18858
Thu May 27|14:24:17.069|A|0002|MSU Received Last Min|19216
Thu May 27|14:25:17.070|A|0002|MSU Received Last Min|19702
Thu May 27|14:26:17.072|A|0002|MSU Received Last Min|20190
Thu May 27|14:27:17.073|A|0002|MSU Received Last Min|19871
```

after:

```
2021-05-27 14:23:17|A|0002|MSU Received Last Min|18858
2021-05-27 14:24:17|A|0002|MSU Received Last Min|19216
2021-05-27 14:25:17|A|0002|MSU Received Last Min|19702
2021-05-27 14:26:17|A|0002|MSU Received Last Min|20190
2021-05-27 14:27:17|A|0002|MSU Received Last Min|19871
```

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you(not my downvote btw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's is a way to do processing line to line (assuming the input is in an input.txt file):

```
cat input.txt | while read line; do dateField=$(echo $line | cut -d '|' -f 1); fields=$(echo $line | cut -d '|' -f 2-);  echo -n `date -d "$dateField" +'%Y-%m-%d'`' '; echo  $fields; done
```

This produces the expected result.

**Explanation**

- `cat input.txt`: set the input;
- `while read line; do`: loop line to line;
- `dateField=$(echo $line | cut -d '|' -f 1)`: assigns the first field (date) to the dateField variable;
- `fields=$(echo $line | cut -d '|' -f 2-)`: assigns the rest of the fields to the fields variable;
- `` echo -n `date -d "$dateField" +'%Y-%m-%d'`' ' ``: format the date as you indicated, without new line (`echo -n ...`), and concat space at the end;
- `echo  $fields`: print the rest of the fields.

Comment: it works perfectly, and commands explanation was helpful to be modified as my convenience